# How to batch rename all files in a folder with numbers at end when all files have different extensions?

Tags: file, batch-file, rename

Im on windows. Got a bunch of images in a folder. Has jpg's png's gif's and jpeg's but when i batch rename, i end up with pic(1).jpg and pic(1).png when i want pic(1).jpg then pic(2).png

Windows 7 btw

Thank you

Comment: You have not asked a question about any specific code. Edit your question.

Comment: Batch renaming and batch files are two completely different animals. I find it difficult to believe that a batch file would rename files using numbers in parentheses and suspect that your question is misplaced. If I am mistaken please add the batch file content to your question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46993764/edit) facility.

Comment: Use freeware (for private usage) multimedia viewer __IrfanView__ which has a __Batch Conversion/Rename__ command in menu __File__ for people who want to rename image files and don't have coding skills. Or use shareware file manager __Total Commander__ which has built-in an even more powerful but very easy to use __Multi-Rename Tool__ in menu __Files__ to rename all selected files (or directories) easily depending on various options a user can specify via a GUI interface and get listed the result before executing the rename operation. Both Windows applications have also a help.